# Sum of inverse powers of Euler's totient.

Tags: convergence-divergence, totient-function

Let $\phi$ be Euler's totient function, and consider the sum:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left({1\over\phi(k)}\right)^s
\end{equation}
For what values of $s$ does this converge/diverge?

According to wolframalpha.com, it diverges even for $s = 100$:
[image]
(https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%281%2F%28totient%28k%29%5E100%29%29)

I found that claim somewhat surprising, the intuition being that $\phi(k)$ is usually not horrendously smaller than $k$, so the sum above should converge if the real part of $s$ is not too small.

Using the product formula for $\phi$, we can give an Euler product expansion of the sum as:
$$
\prod_p \left( 1 + \frac{1}{(p-1)^s} (1 + 1/p^s + 1/p^{2s} + \cdots )\right)
$$
$$
= \prod_p \left( 1 + \frac{1}{(p-1)^s}\frac{1}{1 - 1/p^s} \right)
$$
$$
= \prod_p \left( 1 + \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^s \frac{1}{p^s - 1}\right)
$$
with the product taken over primes. For real $s \ge 2$ this is bounded above by
$$
\prod_p \left( 1 + 2^s \frac{2}{p^s} \right)
$$
Comparing with $\sum_p \frac{1}{p^s}$, I suspect this is in fact convergent for $s \ge 2$, despite what wolframalpha says?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum converges if and only if $s>1$. (If we allow complex values, the sum converges if and only if the real part of $s$ is at least $1$.) The divergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\phi(n)^s}$ for $0<s\le1$ follows from the trivial comparison $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\phi(n)^s} > \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^s}$ (and the divergence for $s\le0$ is even more trivial).

For the complementary case, we want to use the fact that
$\phi(n)$ is always pretty darn close to $n$: for example,
[it is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_rate) that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\phi(n)}{n^{1-\delta}} = \infty$ for any $\delta>0$. (Much stronger bounds are listed there, but this one suffices for us.) In particular, $\phi(n) > n^{1-\delta}$ for sufficiently large $n$, so by the comparison test,
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\phi(n)^s} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^{s(1-\delta)}}$ which converges whenever $s>\dfrac1{1-\delta}$. Since $\delta>0$ can be chosen arbitrarily, we conclude that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\phi(n)^s}$ converges whenever $s>1$.